# parsing of files using AWK with field-separators - does not parse correctly

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that contains data which is separated by D**> sub-string.
It looks like this:

some text here...

```
text: nnD**>24%
text: nnD**>25%
text: nnD**>22%
text: nnD**>3%
```

some text here...

nn stands for float number (0.25 or 9.769 - does not matter)
I need to put into a separate file just sequence of % values: 24, 25,22,3....
so, I did the following:

```
`read B1 <<<$(cat FILE_NAME | awk 'BEGIN {FS="D**>" {print $2}')`
`eecho -e "$B1"`
```

exptect to get the list like this: 24%, 25%, 22%...

but it does not parse it correctly - it simply dumn lot of other strings in the file.
If I do like this:

```
read B1 <<<$(cat FILE_NAME | awk 'BEGIN {FS="*>" {print $2}')
```

it works correctly. Could someone explain to me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you give examples of lines that that first commands gets wrong? Also what version of awk are you using? Also why are those commands in backticks? And I'm assuming the missing `}` in that awk (after `>"`) is just a type?

Comment: What separator would you like to use? Would you like to print out the numbers each on a newline (as per my answer) or all on the same line?

Comment: I have a file which contains some text and:
Lmd0:    0D==>0%
Lmd0:    0D==>27%
.....
Lmd0:    0D**>0%
Lmd1: 0.25D**>0%
....

Comment: Thanks to all of you who have gave very useful examples. I've got your points.

Answer (score 2):

The field separator `FS` value is a regular expression so special characters like `*` need to be escaped. Try something like this:

```
read B1 <<< $(awk 'BEGIN {FS="D[*][*]>"} {print $2}' FILE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're focussing on the wrong part of your input. The numbers and asterisks before the ">" are irrelevant. You should use something like this:

```
awk -F'[>%]' '{print $2}' oldfile > newfile
```

This sets the input field separator to either a ">" or a "%" and prints the second field (the numbers that you are interested in). The output is redirected to `newfile`.

The contents of `newfile` will then be:

```
24
25
22
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`FS="D**>"` says `Set the FS to the character D repeated zero or more times, repeated zero or more times again` since `*` is the RE metacharacter that represents optional repetition.

That makes no sense so if you instead want to set the FS to be `the character D followed by the character * followed by the character *` then the way to write that would be `FS="D\\*\\*"` or `FS="D[*][*]"` to make the `*`s be treated literally instead of as RE metacharacters.

I really don't understand what it is you're trying to do with the rest of the script but I suspect you'd be better off just doing it all in one awk command. If you're just trying to get all of the percent values on one line:

```
$ awk -F'D[*][*]>' '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?OFS:""), $2} END{print ""}' file
24% 25% 22% 3%
```

and if you want to strip off the `%` signs:

```
$ awk -F'D[*][*]>' '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?OFS:""), $2+0} END{print ""}' file
24 25 22 3
```

and if you want to separate them with `,` instead of just a space:

```
$ awk -F'D[*][*]>' -v OFS=', ' '{printf "%s%s", (NR>1?OFS:""), $2+0} END{print ""}' file
24, 25, 22, 3
```

Comment: I suspected this. But due-to some reasons, \\* did not work. [*] works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't say to use `\*`, I said `\\*`. When a string literal is used to store an RE it gets parsed twice, once when the script is read and then again when it is executed so if you want to escape a character you need to add a second escape char.

Comment: I got your point. Actually, I also tried to use \\* but it didnt work as well. Probably there is an issue with awk version (red hat 4.4....)anyways,[*] works pefectly fine.

Comment: I keep saying "try `\\*`" and you keep saying "I tried `\*` and it didn't work". Not sure where the disconnect is. If you're really using `\\*` and it's not working, your awk is severely broken.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `awk`, this problem can also be solved with `sed`:

```
$ B1=$(sed -n 's/.*D\*\*>\(.*%\)/\1/p' input_file)
$ echo $B1
24% 25% 22% 3%
```

Answer (score 0):

The `read` builtin command doesn't read input with multiple lines the way you expect.

```
read B1 < <(awk 'BEGIN{FS="D**>"}{print $2}' FILE_NAME)
```

would only assign `24%` to the variable `B1` because `read` is only taking input from the first line.

In order to capture multiple line output from your Awk command and assign it to a Bash variable, I'd use process substitution.

```
B1=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS="D**>"}{print $2}' FILE_NAME)
```